# First Post Review Queue should have the bar raised for questions

Tags: feature-request, review, new-users, se-quality-project

I think that the first post review queue for answers is probably fine, and am only addressing questions.

Many unfit questions make it past the first post review queue all the time. This can be damaging for the overall quality of the site, but also to new users who in some cases needed help from a reviewer. I believe this is a result of several factors.

- Low traffic posts
  Low quality questions do not receive much traffic, and as a result they are not held to the same level of oversight as they should be.
- The queue is always empty
  This causes users to reflexively act as fast as possible as opposed to reviewing in depth. It is also an indication that making changes to the queue by making it more exclusive can be possible without damaging the effectiveness of the queue.
- One review exits queue
  Any action, including no action needed or even a negative review (shown as "Reviewed" in the history) will remove a post from the queue. Often if a question is vague or low quality it will not receive much traffic. This presents a problem for questions making it to closure when only 20 people view them daily "in the wild".
- Lower rep has access to first post
  It requires only 500 reputation to access the first post review queue. And while 500 reputation is significant, it does not take very long to obtain, and can be obtained without being fully aware of the multiple aspects of question composure.
- First post should really be <10 rep
  Once a low quality question enters the wild from the queue, if it has low traffic it is common for an answerer to upvote the question. This means the poster of the question will no longer trigger the first post review queue.

To address these factors, I believe it could be beneficial to raise the bar for the first post review queue.

- First Answer Review Queue
  No change from current mechanism aside from questions being filtered out.
- Initial Question Review Queue
  Name change to "initial" (defN: existing or occurring at the beginning). Questions asked by users with < 10 reputation enter this queue.
- Require at least 3 reviews to exit the Initial Question queue
  This will give a chance for more eyes on low traffic questions. It will also provide more opportunity to for current users to help new users with a beneficial edit or suggestion.
- Allow a path to triage
  The triage feature seems to help, it is possible to see questions bouncing through it which are works in progress. If all 3 reviews in the Initial Question queue are not "No action needed" then the post enters the triage queue.
- Increase the reputation to be able to access the Initial Question Review Queue

Comment: I feel that the 3k limit is set too high.. not every first question requires closing, but many require editing. It would maybe be beneficial to require just editibg privileges, so 2k

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow - I changed that part since you may be correct in being too strict.